# getstoredproccommand("procedurename",new object[1]) throws 'System.AccessViolationException' in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, oracle11g

```
    public static IEnumerable<PortalList> GetAll()
    {
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
    DbCommand objComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("package 
    name.procedurename", new object[1]);

    var result = new List<PortalList>();
    using (IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(objComm))
    {
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
      result.Add(Construct(rdr));
    }
    }
    return result;
    }
```

and my store procedure is like this

```
PROCEDURE PRC_PROCEDURE (resultset_out OUT TYPES.cursorType)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN resultset_out FOR SELECT * FROM PORTALLISTS;
END PRC_PORTALLISTS_GETALL;
```

i am having error in this line `DbCommand objComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("package name.procedurename", new object[1]);`

if i do this

```
DbCommand objComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("package name.procedurename");
```

error is gone but then i am facing same error`[Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll]` in this line using `(IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(objComm))` . i am using dot.net framework 4 and Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll version is 5.0.0.0. can you guys pls help me?

Comment: what is `new object[1]` in your command

Comment: that is i don't know.. i have this same method with string Listtype . that method code is like this     public static List<PortalList> GetAll(string listType) {   Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();            DbCommand objComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("package 
    name.procedurename", new object[1], listType); var result = new List<PortalList>();  using (IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(objComm))
                      while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(Construct(rdr));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

Comment: public static List<PortalList> GetAll(string listType)
{
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand objComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("package name.procedurename", new object[1], listType);

var result = new List<PortalList>();
using (IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(objComm))
{
 while (rdr.Read())
 {
 result.Add(Construct(rdr));
 }
 }
 return result;
 }     and this code is working fine.

Comment: you can pass out param by `AddOutParameter` see my answer

Answer (score 2):

You have `resultset_out` as out param, you can pass your params like below

```
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand); 
// Output parameters specify the size of the return data.
db.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "resultset_out", DbType.Object, Int32.MaxValue);
```

ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647630.aspx

Comment: ok . let me try this way . i have multiple methods written by previous developer like this DbCommand objComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("package 
    name.procedurename", new object[1]); and i am facing error in those methods but i am not facing any error in this DbCommand objComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("package name.procedurename", new object[1], listType);

Comment: now i am facing same error in this line using (IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(objComm)) ...any suggestion?? beside IDataReader any other method that i can use to retrieve data??